# How to restrict access to a folder on my Javelin S4 NAS?

Tags: windows-7, nas

I just bought a Javelin S4 NAS this morning, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to restrict access to a folder.

By default, it shows up in my Network Places:

[image]

I've created a 2nd user account through the web interface (called "mark") which seems to add another folder here. I set a username and password through the interface, but I can still freely open this folder on my computer; it didn't ask me for any credentials.

Reading online, I found out that it also supports Active Directory, which means I should be able to add some restrictions based on my Windows user account, right? Or does that just control how it shows up in the network?

[image]

By default, it was just part of "WORKGROUP" which I guess is why it shows up in my network like that?

Lastly, it seems to support iSCSI. Apparently I was supposed to allocate a certain amount of space for this when I initially set it up, but I went through the basic wizard and it chose everything for me. Anyway, it appears I do have some space left to create this "iSCSI drive" but I don't really know anything about that, or if that's what I need.

What I need is two-fold:

- I want to share some media on my home network which I can stream via UPnP/DLNA. It appears I can do this just by dropping the media in one of the video, picture, or music folders.
- I want a password-protected folder that only I can access, that I can easily copy files to and from on my windows machine (but not tied to my windows account so that I can log in from another machine if necessary)

Does anyone know how I can go about doing this?

Comment: You probably don't want iSCSI. It's a bit hard to setup. Could you see if there's any place where you can setup permissions for folders?

Comment: @billc.cn: I can only control access (deny/read-only/read-write) to the default folders, not user folders. And I'm not even sure how that works, because I can access those folders no problem...it must have authenticated me as an admin somehow.

Comment: Alternative, can you create new users on the NAS? I guess the NAS uses samba software, so it's more logical if you have to setup separated users as opposed just password proected folders.

Comment: @billc.cn: Yes I can and did create a new user account, as described in my post. My concern is that I can still access it from my network folders freely...never asked for a username/password. I don't have a 2nd machine to check on at the moment though.

Comment: Yes, I think you're probably logged in as admin so you can access all the network shares. Maybe you forgot to assign a password to the admin account? The screen shot seems to suggest you should set both an admin user name and password. Also, in almost all operating systems there's no way to set a password to a folder. Access control is all based on users.

Comment: @billc.cn: I guess that's just another magical thing it did for me. I just downloaded VirtualBox and setup a VM to check...it actually doesn't even show the "admin" or "mark" folders, and rest require a password. I guess I was fretting over nothing after all.